# How do I dynamically access a property inside an angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive when given an array it creates check boxes for that list of items using the Name as the label for the checkbox.

Html

```
<div>
<a style="float:right; margin-bottom: 5px;" ng-click="selectNone()" href="#">Select None</a>
<a style="float:right; margin-bottom: 5px;margin-left: 10px" ng-click="selectAll()" href="#">Select All</a>

<div class="cleared"></div>

<div class="form-input form-list">
    <label ng-repeat="item in valuelist | orderBy:'Name'">
        <input type="checkbox" checklist-model="model" checklist-value="item" /> {{item.Name}}<br />
    </label>
</div>
```

JS

```
    'use strict';

growllApp.directive('checkboxlist', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'scripts/modules/checkboxlist.template.html',
        controller: 'checkboxlistController',
        scope: {
            model: "=",
            value: "=",
            valuelist: "="
        }
    }
}]);

growllApp.controller('checkboxlistController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', '$cookieStore', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $cookieStore) {
    $scope.selectAll = function () {
        $scope.model = angular.copy($scope.valuelist);
    };

    $scope.selectNone = function () {
        $scope.model = [];
    };
}]);
```

Using the directive

```
<checkboxlist ng-show="applyToProducts" model="coupon.Products" value="Name" valuelist="productsList"></checkboxlist>
```

All this works fine in most scenarios.  However, I have a scenario where the array I'm passing in has objects in it that do not have the property "Name" but instead have the property "Title".

How do I use the attribute I have in the directive called "value" for the part that determines the label.

So in the directive html instead of saying {{item.Name}} how can I specify {{item.Title}} by passing in that the property name is title in certain cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the 'value' attribute of your directive to '@' (it means the value will be sent as a string to your directive. You can read more in this [article](https://blog.umur.io/2013/07/02/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/) )

```
scope: {
        model: "=",
        value: "@",
        valuelist: "="
    }
```

and to get the object's property, you can do:

```
  {{item[value]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer suggesting a ternary operator you could simplify that to be something like

```
{{ item.Name || item.Title }}
```

and you could have as many alternatives as you need.

However, a more robust approach I think would be to do like someone else suggested and say

```
scope : {
    ...
    key:'@'
    ...
}
```

where key is the name of the property and the access it like

```
{{ item[key] }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
{{ item.Name ? item.Name : item.Title }}
```

You would probably need to use a [custom comparator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) for the orderBy then.